# fetch api happens before I submit the form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use react js as frontend framework and laravel as backend framework. I also use proxy. I have a function that hanlde submit of my form. Everytime I load my form page I got two responses on my console although I haven't hit the submit button yet. This is my component CreateDaerah. I use function component

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const CreateDaerah = () => {
    const [nama, setNama] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = (url = '', data = {}) => {
        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));;
    }
    

    return(
        <div className="card-create">
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(`/api/provinsi`, nama)}>
                <h1>Form Provinsi</h1>
                <label htmlFor="nama">Nama</label>
                <input type="text" 
                        className="nama-provinsi" 
                        name="nama" 
                        placeholder="masukkan nama"
                />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Also how can I get the nama value from the input? Should I use onChange attribute?

Comment: what response you are getting in console

Comment: You're immediately calling `handleSubmit` rather than passing a reference to the function to the listener. `onSubmit={() => handleSubmit('/api/provinsi', nama)}`.

Comment: @AtalShrivastava I got Response {type: 'basic', url: 'http://localhost:3000/add', redirected: true, status: 200, ok: true, …}

Comment: `onSubmit` accepts a callback function; @Andy is absolutely right.

Comment: @Andy ah I see. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You're calling the `handleSubmit` function immediately on the render, so you either need to pass a *reference* to the function instead with a callback, or just pass the function reference without those arguments.
2. I probably wouldn't pass those arguments. I wouldn't even use a `form` element as elements don't need to be wrapped in it. I'd would declare the URL in the component and place the `handleSubmit` on the button. That way you don't have to deal with the form updating the page.
3. Place an `onChange` handler on your input which calls a function that updates the state, and have the value of that input be the result of the state.

Here's a shorter working example.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  const [ numa, setNuma ] = useState('');

  const url = `/api/provinsi`;

  function handleInput(e) {
    setNuma(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleClick() {
    console.log('Button clicked');
    console.log(`Final state: ${numa}`);
    // fetch(url) using numa state
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input value={numa} onChange={handleInput} />
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: how can i get name value from the input? Should I use onChange attribute?

Comment: @YustinaYasin I've updated my answer so it's a little more clear. I've basically removed the form element because you don't it, and added the submit to the button instead. The input has its own handler that updates the state.

Comment: I have tried your solution but its not updating the database

Comment: You should post another question about that including your server code, as this is a little out of this question's remit. `numa` will be a string so you should just need `body: numa` and it should work based on the code you've presented unless the API is expecting something different like an object.

Comment: I have posted another question with my controller code

Comment: you're right. I should send object not string. Thank you so much. Now it's solved

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are calling `handleSubmit` immediately at each render rather than providing a function to *be* called at submit.  Instead you should update it to something like:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const CreateDaerah = () => {
    const [nama, setNama] = useState('');

    const handleSubmit = (url = '', data = {}) => {
        fetch(url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));;
    }
    

    return(
        <div className="card-create">
            <form onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(`/api/provinsi`, nama)}>
                <h1>Form Provinsi</h1>
                <label htmlFor="nama">Nama</label>
                <input type="text" 
                        className="nama-provinsi" 
                        name="nama" 
                        placeholder="masukkan nama"
                />
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```